# C++ Convert Address of Memory To Value?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

In C++, using the iostream, you can print a variable's memory address. For example:

```
std::cout << &variable << std::endl;
// Example Result: 002AFD84
```

However, what if I wanted to store this memory address into a variable? Such as converting the memory address to a string or double(or int, etc.)? Or even convert that string or double(or int, etc.) back again, to a memory address?

I'd like to do this for various reasons, one being: This would allow me to return the memory address for data within a DLL to a program calling the DLL and it's functions. On top of this, I won't have to keep track of the data itself within the DLL, since the data could then be referenced by it's memory address.

I cannot use pointers in this particular situation due to constraints. The constraints being: The interpreted programming language I am using does not have access to pointers. Due to this, pointers cannot be used to reference the data outside of the DLL.

As a side question, what number format do memory addresses use? They seem to always seems to be 8 characters in length, but I can't figure out what format this is.

Comment: A pointer seems reasonable.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have constraints, that's why I am curious about what I asked.

Comment: What constraints? Normally in a C++ application you pass memory addressed around as pointers

Comment: The DLL can pass pointers around, but if the program I am passing the reference to cannot use pointers, then I have to convert the address into a form of data the program can use for reference.

Comment: What program cannot use pointers, Besides using double to store a pointer is going to have so many problems. (doubles are imprecise).

Comment: And do you mean hexadecimal with your last question? That's just the normal way of displaying an address to humans. The number is stored like any other.

Comment: The person does not really understand the concept of pointers. Also C++ is trying its hardest to be type safe. Why break that contract?

Comment: On the contrary, I understand pointers very well... However, my problem is VERY specific. I can use pointers within the DLL itself; the interpreted language I am linking the DLL to CANNOT use pointers at all. Hence the question.

Comment: @user3519915 [You may want to read about XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - essentially, you aren't asking about your problem, but about your *attempted solution*.

Comment: Normally you would cast pointer to size_t, which is an unsigned value size of a pointer, so it's safe way to do it. E.g. `size_t v=(size_t)p;` and `void *p=(void*)v;` (or use reinterpret_cast if you are a pedantic).

Comment: @millen Thank you for the link. However, I am asking about problem `X` without knowing the solution `Y`. Yet, people assume I absolutely can/have to use pointers, which I've stated, is not possible. The `X/Y` issue doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @user3519915 - So why suggest using doubles? Can the interpreter access the memory based upon this address?

Comment: The reason people think you don't know what you are asking is because the way you formulated the original question, e.g. asking in what format pointer is stored, convert it to double, etc. Thus they are inclined to push you to the right direction rather than give you tools to continue going to the wrong direction.

Comment: @user3519915 You haven't read the link. Your problem is (probably - you haven't told us) "sharing data between DLLs/interpreted language", and you are asking about "converting pointers". These *are* different issues.

Comment: @user3519915 Also, if your interpreted language can't handle pointers, how can you use that value you got? So, you send an `int`. What next?

Comment: Ed I suggested using string/double or even integers as I was unsure which type would be appropriate. Jark, Good point.

Comment: @milleniumbug Exactly what I've been getting at. The point is to pass the memory address to the program of the interpreted language simply to save the memory address for reference. The interpreted language program would pass that reference back to the DLL when it comes time to use the data behind the address.

Comment: @user3519915 - I hope you understand the concept that some datatypes are precise (integers, strings) and some are a represpentation (doubles). For example, how would you store currency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely need to do this I suggest being selective about what types you convert to. Arbitrarily converting pointers to non-pointer types can be problematic and introduce problems that are difficult to detect. This is especially true if you are using `reinterpret_cast` to perform the conversions. One of the more common issues is the size of the destination type between various platforms. When you use something like `reinterpret_cast` you typically don't get warnings about loss of precision during the conversion.

For situations require you to convert a pointer to an integral type I suggest wrapping these conversion in a function template. This will allow you a bit of flexibility in performing the conversion and can perform compile-time size checks to ensure the destination type is large enough to hold the pointer.

Something like the code below might be helpful.

```
template<class DestType, class SourceType>
DestType bubblicious_value_cast(const SourceType& src)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(DestType) >= sizeof(SourceType), "Destination size is too small");
    return reinterpret_cast<DestType>(src);
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = bubblicious_value_cast<int>(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To convert a pointer into a string representation, you can use a string stream. These are similar to the standard I/O streams `std::cin` and `std::cout`, but write to or read from a string rather than performing I/O.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << &variable;
std::string address = oss.str();
```

To convert a pointer into an integer that represents the same address, use `reinterpret_cast`. The type `uintptr_t`, if it exists, is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any pointer value. But I think usually it suffices to use `unsigned long`.

```
unsigned long address = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(&variable);
```

Converting a pointer into a floating-point type seems fairly useless. You would have to convert into an integral type first, then convert to a floating-point type from there.

Comment: Now using reinterpret_cast I can retrieve the address as an integer, however, how would I convert that integer back into a memory address?

Comment: @user3519915 Use another `reinterpret_cast` back to the pointer type.

Comment: For example, like so? `type* Pointer = reinterpret_cast<type*>( Address );`

Comment: @user3519915 Yep, basically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` like this:

```
uintptr_t address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&variable);
```

In 64-bit (or 32-bit) environment memory address has 64-bit (32-bit) length, respectively.

Comment: This is a pretty quick way to lose half the address with a typical 64-bit system.

Comment: `uintptr_t` would at least automatically be the appropriate size.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the 64-bit system.